# Conditioner Modal Rendering When Input Is In Focus State Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

In my react Project, I want a modal to popup when the input field is in the hover state. I'm using the react-bootstrap modal. But the problem I'm having is that it's only the modal button that displays when the input is in the focus state. The modal should pop up automatically when the input is being focused. My code below. Kindly assist

App Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import stays from "./Components/stays.json";

import FancyModalButton from "./Components/FancyModalButton";

export default function SearchGuest() {
  const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(Data);
  const [hasFocus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(stays);
    setFilteredData(stays);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <form action="">
      {hasFocus ? <FancyModalButton /> : null}  
        <input
          onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
          type="text"
          name="guest"
          placeholder="text"
          style={{ border: "1px solid yellow" }}
        />

        <input type="number" name="location" placeholder="number" />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
   
      {console.log(filteredData)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Modal Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import Modal from "styled-react-modal";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function FancyModalButton() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

The Image of What I have

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the page which is currently showing the button only?

Comment: I just added the Image @JahidHasan All I want is to display a modal when the input is focused

Comment: The `show` state variable defaults to `false` in your `FancyModalButton`. Just make sure the `Modal` has the `show` prop set to true when that component gets rendered.